# Clear all dynamically generated usercontrol in mainform on buttonclick on form 2

Tags: c#, winforms

On my main `Form` I have a panel with dynamically generated `UserControl` in it. I want to clear all the `UserControl`s on button click on another `UserControl`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
private Form1 mainForm = null;
public ProductCategoryUC(Form1 callingForm)
{
    mainForm = callingForm as Form1;
    InitializeComponent();
}

public ProductCategoryUC(string Text, Image imagee)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    categorybtn.LabelText = Text;
    categorybtn.Image = imagee;
}

private void categorybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control item in mainForm.productsContainer1.Controls.OfType<UserControl>())
    {
        item.Controls.Clear();
    }
}
```

But getting this error:

> System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: put a break point at foreach and debug to check whether your mainForm is null or not

Comment: Put a check before item.Controls.Clear() -- like if(item.Controls != null) then only clear